# Properly flashing ledger board for pergola or overhanging patio roof

Tags: roof, siding, flashing, pergola, extension

I am wanting to build a roof over our west facing patio to help with the heat of the day. I was thinking either a pergola type structure with a roof on it, or just an overhang. The structure will attach to the 1st floor of the house, directly beneath where the 2nd story of the house sticks out about 20 inches. This overhanging 20 inches will cover the entire length of the ledger board.
The problem is, when the house was initially built it was not code to have a house wrap. When I remove the vinyl siding, there will be nothing but wood there. How should I properly flash this? 
In addition, what is the correct way to attach an angled joist to the ledger board? The roof will be slanting down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How should I properly flash this?

[image]

> what is the correct way to attach an angled joist to the ledger board?

[image][image]

p.s. I think in your application it would be referred to as a *rafter* as opposed to a *joist*.

Comment: Thank you! The picture is especially useful. What kind of hanger is that? Brand?

Comment: Not an endorsement but that particular hanger is made by Simpson.